# Can't finish a mathematical project

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to coding and I am finding this site really helpful. So I have been trying to solve this problem and I am getting erroneous results, so I would be really grateful if you could help me out here.

*The Problem:* Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000. (For example, if we list all the positive integers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9, which sum is 23.)
My code:

```
count = 0
count1 = 0
for x in range(1000): 
      if x % 5 == 0:
          count = count + x
      if x % 3 == 0:
       count1 = count1 + x
print count1 + count
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You double counted multiples of 15.

Answer (score 4):

You want an `elif` in your code so you don't count the same `x` twice but a simpler way is to use an `or` with a single `count` variable:

```
count = 0

for x in range(1000):
      if x % 5 == 0 or x % 3 == 0:
        count += x
```

Which can be done using `sum`:

```
 print(sum(x for x in range(3, 1000) if not x % 5 or not x % 3))
```

For completeness, a working version using your own code:

```
count = 0
count1 = 0
for x in range(1000): 
      if x % 5 == 0:
          count += x
      elif x % 3 == 0:
          count1 += x
print count1 + count
```

`if`s are always evaluated; so, for instance, when `x` is 15 it is evenly divisible by 5 and 3 so you count 15 twice, an `elif` is only evaluated if the previous `if`/`elif` evaluates to `False` so using `elif` only one occurrence of `x` will be added to the total.

Answer (score 0):

Below 10 there is no number being multiple of both 5 and 3. But below 1000 there are several numbers divided exactly by 3 and 5 also (15, 45 ...).

So you need:

```
count=0
for x in range(1000): 
    if x % 5 == 0 or x % 3 == 0:
        count=count + x
print count
```